# ¿Cómo crear una tarjeta de usuario con Stripe usando Node.js?

Tags: nodejs, stripe

Estoy utilizando Stripe como método de pago en mi proyecto de Node.js. Para esto estoy siguiendo [la documentación](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create?lang=node).

Lo que necesito es crear una tarjeta con información como: número de tarjeta, nombre de la persona, fecha de expiración y código de seguridad.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
const createCard = (customer, cardInfo) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stripe.customers.createSource(
      customer,
      {
        source: {
          object: 'card',
          ...cardInfo
        }
      },
      (err, card) => {
        if (err) {
          debug('There was an error while creating a new card')
          reject(err)
        }
        debug(card)
        resolve(card)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

El objeto que mando con `cardInfo` es el siguiente:

```
{
  "number": "4242424242424242",
  "exp_month": "11",
  "exp_year": "2021",
  "cvc": "123",
  "name": "Mi nombre"
}
```

La respuesta que obtengo en el callback es la siguiente:

`Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing."`

Estoy utilizando mi llave de desarrollo.

Comment: Solo espero que no estés intentando guardar los datos de la tarjeta de tus clientes en tu aplicación, ya que eso no sería nada recomendado. Viola las recomendaciones de la [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) (PCI-DSS). Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El flujo ideal es:

1. Crear un card token (por ejemplo utilizando Stripe.js / Elements)
2. Obtener el token creado
3. Actualizar el customer con el token en vez de enviar directamente los datos de la tarjeta.

Puedes ver una guía completa aquí https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#react , pero la lógica principal es:

```
const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);
const result = await stripe.createToken(card)
if (result.error) {
  // ...
} else {
  // Aquí llamas a tu servidor, el cual actualiza el Customer.
  stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
}
```

Te comento de todos modos que para empezar consideres otros modelos como Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout . Checkout es la manera más simple para empezar a aceptar pagos con Stripe.

Comment: ¿Esto se serviría para guardar la tarjeta sin realizar un pago? Lo que necesito es poder guardar detalles de tarjetas para posteriormente en algún punto de la historia poder hacer un pago. Es decir, lo que necesito ahora es poder tener una pantalla donde guarde tarjetas usando número de tarjeta, nombre, fecha de vencimiento y cvc. Este token podría usarlo para asignar esa tarjeta a mi CustomerID correcto?

Comment: @akko Stripe.js / Elements te permite guardar un método de pago sin realizar un cargo.

Checkout sin embargo está enfocado en la compra de un producto o servicio en particular, por lo que Checkout no te serviría para sólamente guardar los datos. El Customer y PaymentMethod sí quedan almacenados para realizar más cargos a la misma tarjeta en el futuro.

Comment: Entonces lo que mandaría a mi función después del `customer` es `{ source: 'EL TOKEN DE LA TARJETA' },` ¿Cierto?

Comment: Parecido; en vez de `source`, sería `payment_method`. La guía completa está acá: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web

Comment: Según los [docs de actualizar usuario](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-source) 

Para agregar una tarjeta se usa el key `source` pero esto elimina los ya guardados previamente. Si uno quiere tener una colección de tarjetas, como es mi caso, debe revisar la [docs de crear tarjeta](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create?lang=node)

Comment: Esta guía es diferente; primero creas el customer, y al confirmar el intent le referencias el customer a través del client_secret. Así queda el payment method asociado al customer.

Comment: Otra pregunta: ¿Es posible crear un token de tarjeta utilizando los SDK de ios y android? Mi intención sería la misma, generar una tarjeta y asociarla a un customer.

Comment: Claro! En esa misma guía hay instrucciones para Web, iOS, y Android (busca un tab con el cual puedes hacer el switch).